# IF statement around styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to do this? Page is in HTML, uses javascript

I have left navgation which uses a style  On certain pages I want to use another style so I have created a new class

so what I want to do is:

```
if page = a
display leftmenu class
else
display
left class
```

Can someone help me with the code so that it will work?

Comment: I think you can do this in SCSS

Comment: Removed your Java tag since this is not a question about Java

Comment: You can create "generic" styles, then override them when another class it present: `.foo { color: red; }` (color all elements with class foo red) `.bar .foo { color: green; }` (when foo is inside a bar color it green instead)

Comment: The question is kind of vague, there are several answers depending on what your situation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always have an `id` on the `html` element that represents the current page, something like:

```
<html id="home-page">, <html id="about-page">
```

etc.

With that at hand you can easily accomplish what you're after using:

```
div.leftmenu {general styling}

#about-page div.leftmenu {styling specific to the About page}
```

Also, leftmenu is a really bad name. What if you want it on the right on the #home-page?

Answer (score 3):

```
body div.leftmenu {
   styles for other non-display pages
}

body.display div.leftmenu {
   styles for left menu on a 'display' page
   override any styles defined above
}
```

Comment: The cms system I am using is a bit strange. I only have access to the leftnav code and the css and cant access the body area which is why I am trying to come up with an if statement to use in left nav code

Comment: CSS is 'flat' across the entirety of a page. If you can insert a `<style>` block into the leftnav's output, then you can use the above stuff, as long as the parent selectors leading up to your nav block are right.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use JavaScript, like you suggest:

```
var page = 'whereveryougetpagefrom';
var elementToStyle = document.getElementById('nameofelement');

if (page == 'a') {
    elementToStyle.className += " leftmenu";
} else {
    elementToStyle.className += " left";
}
```

However, this is best done in CSS using styles.

Comment: I don't even see anything that would insinuate PHP is a solution?

Comment: Me totally misreading the tag on the question! :) Updated to use JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's dynamic, using a server-sided language would probably make more sense for what you're trying to achieve.

You could send the prefered style through a `get` variable.

If you are trying to do this dynamically, clicking a link can change element's className.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('sidebar');
elem.className = 'leftmenu'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an ID to your body tag:

```
<body id="a">
```

Then add styles:

```
body h1 {
  color: black;
}

body#a {
  color: red;
}
```